# Error handler for Flutter Exception caught by SVG (flutter_svg package)

Tags: flutter, svg

I get rendering exception when SVG retrieved from network contains disallowed tags or elements. I cannot use `svg cleaner` or any other tool, because I just need to get SVG data from remote datasource where I have no access. I would like to just handle the error exception - something similar to `Image.asset(errorBuilder => ...)`. There is no such option in `SvgPicture`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to retrieve plain data using `Dio` or `Http` package.

```
Future<dynamic> fetchData(String url) async {
  try {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    Response response = await dio.get(url);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data: $error');
  }
}
```

Then use `FutureBuilder` to wait for the response.

```
Widget getSvgPictureOrErrorWidget(Widget errorWidget, String svgAssetUrl) =>
  FutureBuilder(
    future: _futureSvgOrError(errorWidget, svgAssetUrl),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) =>
        snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data! : const SizedBox(),
  );
```

And finally, check for any exception (http exception, rendering exception). In case of error use `errorWidget`.

```
Future<Widget> _futureSvgOrError(Widget errorWidget, String svgAssetUrl) async {
  try {
    final svgAsset = await fetchData(svgAssetUrl); // http exception
    await SvgParser().parse(svgAsset, warningsAsErrors: true); // rendering exception
    return SvgPicture.string(
      svgAsset,
      height: 40,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('WARN: Error occured while loading asset $svgAssetUrl: $e');
    return errorWidget;
  }
}
```

Actual solution is to manually try to parse SVG data (`SvgParser().parse(svgDataString)`) and in case of exception use `errorWidget`. `warningAsErrors` has to be set to `true` for exception to be evaluated as an error and caught in the catch block. Hope it helps someone until `errorBuilder` is implemented in `SvgPicture.network(errorBuilder => ..)`. I hope it will be.